# Prove, graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

Could anyone explain me how to prove this:

We have $2$ colors. Red and Blue. If we color in a complete graph $K_n$ random edges with random colors, then there exists spanning tree, which contains only edges with given colors.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I meant spanning tree. I have edited the post.

Comment: I suspect the problem is to show there exists a spanning tree which contains only edges *of a single color*.  The mention of "random edges with random colors" is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: One way is to prove it by induction on $n$. Assume that the result is true for $n$, and consider $K_{n+1}$. Let $v$ be a a vertex of $K_{n+1}$, and let $E_v$ be the set of edges of $K_{n+1}$ having $v$ as an endpoint. Consider two cases:

- $E$ is monochromatic.
- $E$ contains edges of both colors. This is where you’ll use the induction hypothesis.